What does this error mean? do not delete recursively without -r
good afternoon, I tried to remove a folder called css from the stage area with the following command "git rm --cached", but I get this error
"fatal: not removing 'css' recursively without -r." Then I removed them with the reset without problems, which led me to find out the difference between these 2, but I don't understand this error
I hope I can understand this difference since it has never happened to me before. and may it be useful for others who want to delve into this error

Just like ordinary rm, git rm won't recursively delete a directory unless you explicitly ask it to

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

“Recursively” in this context means deleting files across directories: you recurse into one or more directories and delete the files and directories (recursively).

Instead of using git rm --cached css (as I expect that you did),
use git rm --cached -r css. The r flag means that delete recursively. E.g. if run git rm --cached -r on a file tree like
hello
├── hello.txt
└── hello_2
    └── who

then the command would delete, who, then hello_2, then hello.txt, then, finally, hello.
